# Image over create project directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin. I am trying to create new project wizard and i am successfull in doing so. But when the project is created, I want to show my image on right-top corner of the project directory image. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the small image used in Projects / Package explorer and elsewhere.

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.projectNatureImages` extension point to declare the overlay image. This requires that you have added a `nature` to the project you have created.